# Why do I keep getting unresolved externals for my program?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I keep getting unresolved externals when I try to run this code in Visual Studio.

> **Structure Time Assignment for College**
>
> Create a structure called Time that has members days, hours, minutes,
>   and seconds as ints.
>     Create an instance of Time and initialize the members.
>     Create a function to normalize the time when values are added to it.
>
> For example, after adding values to the hours, call the normalize
>   function which should see if the hours > 24.
>     If so, add 1 to the days member and reset hours by subtracting 24
>   from the current value. 
>     DO the same for minutes and seconds over 59.
>
> Your main program should add values to hours, minutes and seconds and
>   after each, call the normalize function to properly set the values.
>
> Output the members after each update.  Assume hours use a 24-hour
>   clock.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Struct time
{
int days = 0;
int hours = 0;
int minutes = 0;
int seconds = 0;

};

void normalize();

int main()
{
int clockRepeating;

for (clockRepeating = 0; clockRepeating < 150; clockRepeating++)
{
normalize();
}

return 0;
}

void normalize(Time &timenormalize)
{

if (timenormalize.days > 31)
timenormalize.days = 1;
if (timenormalizehours > 24)
{
timenormalize.hours = 0;
timenormalize.days++;
}
if (timenormalize.minutes > 59)
{
timenormalize.minutes = 0;
timenormalize.hours++;
}
if (time normalize.seconds > 59)
{
timenormalize.seconds = 0;
timenormalize.minutes++;
cout << timenormalize.days, timenormalize.hours, timenormalize.minutes, timenormalize.seconds;
}
else
timenormalize.seconds++;
cout << timenormalize.days, timenormalize.hours, timenormalize.minutes,timenormalize.seconds;
```

Comment: What are the exact error messages you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

The signature you declared for `void normalize();` does not match the signature as it's defined in this file (`void normalize(Time &timenormalize)`).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fixed up version of your code. First the compilation errors:

- changed `Struct` to `struct`: `struct` is a key word, must be lowercase;
- changed `Time` to `struct time` in `void normalize(..)`: symbols are case sensitive: `Time` isn't declared, but `struct time` is;
- added missing `.` to `if (timenormalizehours)`: `if (timenormalize.hours)`;
- added `}` to the end of the file (probably copy/paste error).

And then the linker error `undefined reference to 'normalize'`:

- change function declaration `void normalize()` to `void normalize(struct time &)`: you *declare* the `normalize` function without parameters, but *define* it with one parameter.

And then finally the compilation error this introduces:

- change the `normalize();` call to `normalize( mytime );` because it takes a paramter
- and declare a local variable `struct mytime` to pass as the parameter.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct time
{
    int days = 0;
    int hours = 0;
    int minutes = 0;
    int seconds = 0;
};

void normalize(struct time &);

int main()
{
    int clockRepeating;
    struct time mytime;

    for (clockRepeating = 0; clockRepeating < 150; clockRepeating++)
    {
        normalize( mytime );
    }

    return 0;
}

void normalize(struct time &timenormalize)
{

    if (timenormalize.days > 31)
        timenormalize.days = 1;
    if (timenormalize.hours > 24)
    {
        timenormalize.hours = 0;
        timenormalize.days++;
    }
    if (timenormalize.minutes > 59)
    {
        timenormalize.minutes = 0;
        timenormalize.hours++;
    }
    if (timenormalize.seconds > 59)
    {
        timenormalize.seconds = 0;
        timenormalize.minutes++;
        cout << timenormalize.days, timenormalize.hours, timenormalize.minutes, timenormalize.seconds;
    }
    else
        timenormalize.seconds++;
    cout << timenormalize.days, timenormalize.hours, timenormalize.minutes,timenormalize.seconds;
}
```

It prints a series of `0`. Now it's up to you to put some values in `struct time mytime`. I hope this helps!